# Qual é uma boa expressão brasileira e inglesa do termo “resmungão”?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, tradução-inglês

Procurei por sinônimos da palavra “resmungão” no site sinonimos.com e não encontrei boas palavras que traduzissem o termo em que eu estava pensando… Pois bem, eu pensei se haveria uma expressão de um certo “dito popular” que as pessoas usavam para chamar as pessoas de “resmungonas” porque eu acho que, sinceramente, escrever a palavra “resmungão”/“resmungona” em uma obra é muito feio… A energia é meio chata, sabe? Ainda mais em uma obra de alto teor que estou tentando produzir…

Enfim, gostaria de perguntar se a comunidade brasileira ou portuguesa daqui, do Stack Enxchange — ***droga, quase… *Quaseeee* acertei xD. Oh. Enfim…*** —, poderia me ajudar com uma expressão portuguesa e uma expressão inglesa com o mesmo significado de “resmungão” — por favor, expressão brasileira, não portuguesa. Aí, *ceis* apelam xD — e… gostaria dessa expressão para eu poder fazer uma referência aqui a um conceito de meus trabalhos. Só.

Pois bem, o que eu gostaria de pedir mesmo é por uma expressão do item descrito no texto, tanto no português quanto no inglês, ou pelo menos um sinônimo que seja mais bonito e legal de ser falado que “resmungão”, porque “resmungão” é chato, sabe? Quero falar “resmungão” de um jeito legal… Eu gosto.

Comment: Velorace, bem-vindo ao site! Uma pergunta: tenho tua permissão de editar a tua pergunta para pô-la num portuguê mais formal?

Comment: Oh, olá schive... Bem, eu sinceramente pensei que minha pergunta estava boa... Não está bem assim? Se tiver algum erro ou alguma coisa extremamente informal (talvez o meu item em negrito e italico xD) você poderia mencionar para mim, por favor? Ao invés de você editar para mim o texto, eu gostaria de saber em que sentidos você acha que minha pergunta poderia ser melhorada ou, tornada mais formal... Eu fiz bem formal, eu acho... Não está excessivamente informal, não é??? xD

Gostaria que você relatasse primeiro os pontos que gostaria de mudar, só para eu entender o que eu posso melhorar. Obg.

Comment: Meu santo senhor! O meu primeiro comentário deu 600 caracteres exatos, UAU!!!! 

Comment: Oh, sim, pensando bem...

Creio que lhe dou essa permissão sim. Quero ver como você melhora o meu texto na pratica. Estou muito curioso, Schiliive!

Gosto de ver como as pessoas também editam para melhorarem os meus textos...

Vou manter uma cópia aqui para ver o que mudou. De toda forma, acho que o seu estará melhor, e mais formal mesmo para o site. Obrigado!

Comment: Só por favor, tente manter a emoção de meu texto e minhas palavras xD 

Comment: Velorace, para a edição ir ao ar tens que aceitá-la e também podes editar em cima da minha edição, então, te será mais uma sugestão de edição do que uma edição propriamente dita.

Comment: Oh, que lindo! Sim, aceito. Gostaria de ver, obrigado!!!

Comment: Velorance, na realidade, vou apenas melhorar o uso da gramática.

Comment: Ok... Obrigado.

Vamos ver como fica.

Como eu aceito a edição?

Comment: Não estou encontrando nenhum botão...?

Comment: Mas... Por que me chamastes de velorance derrepente? Todo mundo faz isso e eu odeio tanto... =(

Comment: Quando houver uma proposta de edição à tua pergunta, serás notificado para decidires se a aceitas, editas em cima dessa edição ou recusas. Eu te chamei de “velorance” por erro; desculpa.

Comment: Ufa obrigado... Me sinto melhor agora... Achei que era um pressagio do mal da santa cruz... :(

Ok, obrigado... Irei esperar pela sua edição =) 

A minha pergunta já está no ar, por sinal? Nunca estive por aqui xD

Comment: Velorace, sim, a tua pergunta já está no ar. Por sinal, se fores querer, sente-te livre para recusares a minha proposta de edição, e acabei editando de mais, eu acho. Porém, talvez a edição tenha que ser revisada por um “membro confiável”…

Comment: Schilive, meu amigo...

Eu aprovei a sua edição por que, realmente... Eu fiquei impressionado com a forma que eu escrevi, e com a forma que você escreveu...

É...

Realmente, tão interessante...

A sua gramática, realmente, ficou muito bonita... meu amigo...

Gostaria de lhe dizer... Que você corrigiu, realmente, muita coisa que eu poderia ter aprimorado... e eu cheguei até a salvar aqui a sua edição, para eu nunca me esquecer do modo de fala que você me recomendou a me dirigir... Que eu vi, realmente... Como sendo de uma beleza e de padrões tão altos...

Obrigado, meu amigo...

Comment: Você me ajudou bastante...

Verei, se apartir de hoje... Eu possa melhorar o meu nivel e lugar de fala, pois parece que as vezes, realmente... Eu falo, e escrevo as coisas, em muita informalidade... Mesmo quando penso que estou sendo formal. Eu acho, que você me ajudou bastante hoje...

De toda forma, me impressionei como a "gramática" que você disse ter corrigido, mas parece ser como um... Hábito, e linguajar de fala... Sabe? Não se trata somente de ordens gramáticais... Se trata, também, de como as pessoas utilizam elevam e simbolizam as suas falas... É algo, tão natural, espontâneo e..

Comment: complexo...

Verei mais, nos dias de hoje ou de amanhã.. Como poderei pensar, em como os Niveis e Modos de Falas das pessoas podem ser melhorados, e muito, ao mesmo padrão daqui onde as pessoas escrevem nesse lugar... Obrigado, meu amigo =)

Comment: Isto na verdade são duas perguntas: pedes um sinónimo "menos chato" para resmungão, em pt-BR; e pedes uma tradução para inglês. A primeira pede a "tag" [tag:portugues-brasileiro] e a segunda pede a tag [tag:tradução-inglês]...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não há um equivalente exacto em inglês para o adjectivo *"resmungão"* - o mais próximo talvez seja [impudent](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/impudent). (De seguida vamos examinar as palavras semelhantes e as particularidades pelas quais nenhuma tradução capta a *"nunce"* exacta do resmungão.)

Para começar resmungão é um adjectivo e a maioria das palavras próximas em inglês ou são verbos ou são substantivos. Vejamos a definição simples do adjectivo:

> [res·mun·gão](https://dicionario.priberam.org/resmung%C3%A3o)
> adjectivo e nome masculino
>
> Que ou o que resmunga.

A palavra mais próxima de captar o sentido de *"resmungão"* é o verbo [*"retort"*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/retort) (por semelhança com o Português retorquir). É mais próximo do que [*"argumentative"*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/argumentative) porque o resmungão não precisa propriamente de estruturar um argumento, basta-lhe resmungar retorquindo.

A semântica do verbo *"resmungar"* já permitiría a tradução para o adjectivo [Grumpy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Grumpy). Mas aqui temos um problema de exactidão que se vai manter sobre as aproximadamente 20 palavras differentes do inglês que sendo próximas nunca vão ser exactas: O adjectivo *"resmungão"* caracteriza mais o acto *"refilar"* do que a [*"rabugice"*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/rabugice) da pessoa - enquanto o verbo *"resmungar"* tal como o adjectivo *"grumpy"* dão características ao **refilão** que o adjectivo por si não tem.

> [res·mun·gar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/resmungar)
> verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Falar entre dentes e com rabugice.
>    verbo intransitivo
> 2. Dar sinais de descontentamento, dizendo coisas desagradáveis em voz baixa.
>    verbo pronominal
> 3. Murmurar-se.

É nesta linha que podemos analisar as restantes palavras do inglês, a maioria dividem-se caracterizando as pessoas e as mensagens em três grupos: Os argutos-engraçados (*"witty"*), os sabichões (*"wise guy"*) e os irascíveis (*"grouchy"*) mas nenhuma das palavras -ao contrário do *"resmungão"* e *"refilão"*- é focada no retorquir independente da forma, do conteúdo, e da intenção da pessoa.

No grupo do irascíveis:

- grouchy
- grumpy
- cranky
- snarky
- snappy
- pettish
  etc...

No grupo dos sabichões:

- [smart aleck](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/smart-aleck)
- [wise guy](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wise+guy)
- [repartee](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/repartee)
  etc...

No grupo dos bem humorados (witty)

- [banterer](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/banterer)
- [quippy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/quippy)
- [witty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/witty)
  etc...

Answer (score 1):

Só agora entendi (sou nova aqui, desculpe).
Você quer um termo mais formal para "resmungão", eu creio que em português, possa associar à reclamação. O termo sugerido seria "reclamona" ou, em algum texto "aquela que reclama de tudo". Em inglês, eu sugiro a mesma coisa: "
just complain"

Answer (score 0):

Em português, acostumamos dizer reclamão.

Answer (score -1):

Talvez em inglês você possa usar *[kvetcher](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/kvetcher)*

Comment: Bem vindo user8916! A pergunta pede uma expressão brasileira, além da inglesa que já citaste, poderia adicionar uma para que sua resposta fique completa? Ainda, se possível, poderia colocar referências (a um dicionário online, possivelmente) que confirme que tuas respostas são corretas?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/kvetcher

Comment: Isso é inglês mesmo?